# Swift - Alamofire .POST with parameters problem

Tags: ios, swift, parameters, alamofire

I want to sent a request with parameters, and I've a problem with the parameters sequence. I need to sent something like that:

```
 let parameters: Parameters = [
                     "name":"someName",
                     "parameters": {
                        "searchingMore": "[{\"name\": \"\(items.name)\",\"surname\": \"\(items.surname)\"}]"
                }] as Dictionary
```

And I'm always getting the Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';' and Expected expression problem on the searchingMore line.
I just want to know how to send the table as a parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing the scopes `{}` with `[]` as follows -

```
let parameters: Parameters = [
            "name":"someName",
            "parameters": [
                "searchingMore": "[{\"name\": \"\(items.name)\",\"surname\": \"\(items.surname)\"}]"
            ]
        ] as Dictionary
```

Comment: That's ok! Just keep in mind curly braces doesn't work in parameters unless it is wrapped within a string.